# Fastest NAS and NAS with the best Performance/price ratio

Tags: network-attached-storage, storage

What is the fastest (Gbit) NAS available?

What NAS has the best price/performance ratio?

This is for small servers / home usage

Comment: Please ask separate questions next time.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building your own OpenSolaris server backed with ZFS, using iSCSI exports, frankly.

Drobos suck, and any consumer-grade NAS you get is going to cost you more than building a complete OpenSolaris box.

Comment: yes, and if you use the Nexenta OpenSolaris-based distro, you get a nice debian-style userland rather than ghastly solaris-like userland.

Comment: What's wrong with Drobo? Would you still build an OpenSolaris box given Oracles choices?

Comment: According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris), OpenSolaris has been discontinued.  Is this still a viable alternative?

Answer (score 7):

I think ZFS is a bit overkill. Considering that building a box and doing all the manual work requires extensive knowledge and time (and $$$), I wouldn't recommend it unless that's what you want/need. It sounds like you're looking for a simple consumer-level NAS device, but I can't tell from your question what your exact needs are.

If best performance is what you want in a NAS, IMO the Netgear ReadyNAS pro (6-disks) is the way to go. It's a fantastic unit and has lots of features that are ideal for either SOHO or just the house. It comes in two flavors: business and pioneer. It's pricey ($1200 for pioneer; $1500 for pro) and probably overkill, but I find that performance wise, ReadyNAS Pro line is above the rest. You can upgrade the processor and RAM as well. Google for some reviews. There are plenty that measure it's I/O and other performance metrics. Oh, and the Pro version also supports iSCSI!

Netgear has heavily marketed the ReadyNAS (rightfully so) and there's a real solid community that backs up the device so if you have questions or need help, there's someone to contact. I'm not a huge Netgear fanboy, but this product was originally built by Infrant who I really thought put a great deal of thought into the ReadyNAS device. Netgear has equally shown its commitment to the ReadyNAS.

I'd also recommend the newer Drobo Pro, but I'm not sure how well it does in terms of performance. The Drobo is pretty flexible when it comes to disks so if versatility is something you need, maybe a Drobo would be appropriate.

Price performance ratio is much tougher question to answer seeing as you really need to clarify what you intend for the NAS to do. If you're doing just simple file sharing and media streaming, there are numerous NAS devices on the market that can easily do that for cheap. Are you using the NAS for VM storage via iSCSI? Are you storing all your media on the device? Do you want to use rsync to backup data remotely? Is this for a business or just home? How many disks to you want to use? What kind of RAID level were you looking for?

You need to be more specific with your goal and perhaps a budget and I think SF can help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll have a look at the ReadyNAS. I'll use it also as a ISCSI VMware device. If solaris is no strategic goal and no knowledge is there, then might it be really cost intensive.

Comment: Some of the other suggestions are also solid options. Thecus is another vendor in the NAS market with a good rep for speed and pricing. I looked into building a FreeNAS server for myself and I haven't tried it out, but the documentation and the features look good and you can't beat free!

Another vendor I'd also recommend is QNAP. They have great linux based NAS devices with a wide variety of models. They aren't as upgradable as other NASes, but give them a look too. I own a QNAP TS-409 Pro and so far it's really been stable and relatively simple to manage.

Answer (score 5):

Performance/Price ratio..  How about a dual core atom nettop with a couple of 1T drives in a mirror.  Total cost about $400.  Cheaper than a Drobo, but not as 'cool'.

You don't tell us what your desired size is or what 'fast' means to you.  Without more info it's difficult to make an informed recommendation

Comment: An informed recommendation statisfy my needs absolutly. 
Default Windows on a nettop for storage issues? Maybe there is no Linux/Unix support on the most nettops.

Comment: I installed CentOS 5.3 on my nettop with no issues.  I even installed via PXEBoot.

Answer (score 3):

Dell has a NS500 for arround $3k use MS storage server.. you can add an iscsi target to it.  I used one in the past for a VMWare cluster that had 150+ Vm on it.  Never had a problem.

Now I run on an EMC Cx4 which is more like $30k ;)

Comment: Depending on the CX4 and the options it can be quite a bit more.  Ours was over $200k including the software packages we bought.

Comment: Nowadays, software licences have become so expensive in relation to hardware.

Comment: True... 30k is basicly one DAE!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd look into Thecus products.  We have a Thecus N5200 as our onsite backup storage target, which locally stores backups for retrieval purposes, and is blazing fast.

We're currently looking into purchasing more for use as a camera storage backup system.  Either the N5200 (5 disk cube style) or an N8800 (8 disk rack mount).  From what I read on the 8800, it is blazing fast as well.

The only downside to Thecus products is the interface is a little lacking in design.  As far as I can tell, it was built by great people with English as their second language and more experience designing robust backend systems than easy-to-use frontends.  They are very "set it and forget it" though, if you won't be messing with anything on a regular basis.

Comment: +1 for Thecus. As  NAS, I seriously like these. I got a N5200 last week, and after 15mins I was good to go, with LDAP auth and everything.

Comment: ++! I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind building the box yourself, [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) is an alternative.  Power of BSD with an Open Source price.  FreeNAS 0.7RC1 includes ZFS support.

Comment: Building it myself is also an option! But I like the "blackbox" characteristics of pre-configured NAS devices.

Answer (score 3):

Like a number of people recommended build your own box, unless you have the budget to buy from a storage vendor. The problem is that most consumer grade solutions tend to have fatal flaws that will impact the end result.

Look in to OpenSolaris, or Openfiler which I find to be very good.

Answer (score 2):

Anything but DLINK.  I, together with many many unfortunate DNS-323 users, experience horrible data loss incidents with DNS-323.

http://wiki.dns323.info/information:known_issues

http://forum.dsmg600.info/viewtopic.php?id=885

Comment: Dammit! The article looks horrible. I'll never gonna buy a DNS-*
I've made also bad experience with DLINK usb wlan sticks.

Comment: Even worse, the issue was discovered and published for years and they never release any patch to fix it.

Comment: I've heard nothing but good regarding the DNS-323.  I have one and it works just fine.  But I have heard you have to erase drive 1 to add drive 2.  AFAICT, that's the only real problem if you have 1.06 firmware.

Comment: Any version of firmware is reported to have the same problem to date.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a QNAP TS-509 Pro 5-bay NAS.  Does very nicely performance-wise;  dual gigabit ethernet and support for 802.3ad.  Reasonably priced,  too.  [www.qnap.com](http://www.qnap.com)

Comment: Got the same NAS, too. On a GBit link i get ~85 MB/s on a CIFS transfer. There's plenty of features. Was extremely reliable for me since i bought (2,5y).